# Convert a string value to a date value in vba

Tags: excel, format-conversion, vba

In order to ease the data entry, I am allowing users to enter the date as "ddmmyyyy" without "/", e.g, "12032017" .  After the entry I want to update the target cell with value "dd/mm/yyyy", e.g, "12/03/2017".
At the start the format of the target cell is set to "General" but as soon as the date value is calculated, format of the cell is automatically changed to "dd/m/yyyy".
I have tried to use both the General and date format. Below is the VBA code

```
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D11:D510")) Is Nothing Then
    If Not (Target.Value = "") Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False   ' very important
    Target.Value = Left(Target.Value, 2) & "/" & Mid(Target.Value, 3, 2) & 
    "/" & Right(Target.Value, 4)
    Application.EnableEvents = True   'very important
    End If
    End If
```

Comment: `12032017` is not a valid recognizable date that Excel will automatically change, so simply changing the format will not work.  You will need vba in a Worksheet_Change event, that parses the string and returns a date, that you then can format properly.

Comment: @ScottCraner, thank you for the reply. Yes, I am using a macro and below is the code;                                                                                       
                                                         
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D11:D510")) Is Nothing Then
    If Not (Target.Value = "") Then
      Application.EnableEvents = False   ' very important
      Target.Value = Left(Target.Value, 2) & "/" & Mid(Target.Value, 3, 2) & 
        "/" & Right(Target.Value, 4)
        Application.EnableEvents = True   'very important
        End If
       End If

Comment: Please put the code in the Original Post using [edit] not in comments.

Comment: Just added the code in the original post. please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still returning a string that looks like a date and not an actual date,  Use DateSerial:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D11:D510")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.NumberFormat = "@"
    If Not (Target.Value = "") Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False   ' very important
        Target.Value = DateSerial(Right(Target.Value, 4), Mid(Target.Value, 3, 2), Left(Target.Value, 2))
        Target.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        Application.EnableEvents = True   'very important
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Scott, I am getting the overflow error on the   If Not (Target.Value = "") Then   statement

Comment: Its working fine now by setting the format of the target cell as general instead of date.   Thanks for your time

Comment: Scott, I am getting the overflow error whenever I try to change the value second time. For example, at the start the Target cell format is set to "General" and the Macro works fine. This Target.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: @Ehsan see edit, we need to change the format back to text, before doing the testing.

Comment: Yes Scott you are right. I did this and It was working fine.   thanks for your help